# Как добавить ключ-значение в словарь?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список, словари

Есть двумерный список `user_list`:

```
user_list = [[{'first_name': 'Svetochek',
   'id': 19,
   'last_name': 'Alenky',
   'city': {'id': 2, 'title': 'Saint Petersburg'}},
  {'first_name': 'Tatyana',
   'id': 34,
   'last_name': 'Plutalova',
   'city': {'id': 2, 'title': 'Saint Petersburg'}}]]
```

Нужно получить значения городов (`['city']['title']`)
Добавить их в словарь. При этом нужно рассчитать количество городов.
Словарь должен иметь вид:

```
{
    'Moscow': '2',
    'Saint Petersburg: '3',
}
```

Итерируюсь так:

```
city_dict = {}

for row in user_lists:
    for a in row:
        if a['city']['title'] not in city_count():
            city1 = a['city']['title']
            city_dict = ...
```

При `city_count[city1] = 1` получаю ошибку:

```
if a['city']['title'] not in city_count():
TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable
```

Если так:

```
for list in user_lists1:
    for row in list:
        city = row['city']['title']
        city_count[city] = city_count.get(city, 0) + 1
```

то
Получаю ошибку:
Traceback (most recent call last):
line 40, in 
city = row['city']['title']
KeyError: 'city'

Comment: https://pythonist.ru/kak-dobavit-element-v-slovar/

Comment: https://coderoad.ru/8214932/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5-python

Comment: list - зарезервированное слово, не стОит использовать его в качестве имени переменной

Comment: Да, согласен. Изменю.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так, через [dict.get()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get):

```
result = dict()
for each in user_list:
    city = each['city']['title']
    result[city] = result.get(city, 0) + 1
print(result)
```

Для тестового:

```
user_list = [
  {'first_name': 'Svetochek',
   'id': 19,
   'last_name': 'Alenky',
   'city': {'id': 2, 'title': 'Saint Petersburg'}},
  {'first_name': 'Tatyana',
   'id': 34,
   'last_name': 'Plutalova',
   'city': {'id': 2, 'title': 'Saint Petersburg'}},
  {'first_name': 'Pupsik',
   'id': 13,
   'last_name': 'Figleva',
   'city': {'id': 1, 'title': 'New York'}},]
```

выведет:

```
{'Saint Petersburg': 2, 'New York': 1}
```

---

**UPD** если среди словарей могут встретиться такие, что не содержат записей с ключем `city`, стОит добавить проверку `each.get('city')`:

```
result = dict()
for each in user_list:
    if each.get('city'):
        city = each['city']['title']
        result[city] = result.get(city, 0) + 1
print(result)
```

Comment: делаю так:
 `for item in user_lists1:
    for a in item:
        city = a['city']['title']
        city_count[city] = city_count.get(city, 0) + 1 `
Потому то список списков.
Получаю ошибку: <ipython-input-170-1db44560a255> in <module>
      1 for item in user_lists1:
      2     for a in item:
----> 3         city = a['city']['title']
      4         city_count[city] = city_count.get(city, 0) + 1
      5 

KeyError: 'city'

Comment: @spacenew покажите структуру user_lists или, лучше, полностью? могут быть словари без ключа city?

Comment: Вероятней всего дело в том, что в некоторых строках отсутсвует ['city'], поэтому возникает ошибка. Вот часть списка, в которой это видно:
`
[[{'first_name': 'Lena',
   'id': 476,
   'last_name': 'Samuylova',
   'bdate': '25.3.1988',
   'city': {'id': 1, 'title': 'Moscow'}},
  {'first_name': 'Darya',
   'id': 485,
   'last_name': 'Pavlova',
   'deactivated': 'banned'},
  {'first_name': 'Anatoly', 'id': 510, 'last_name': 'Karpenko'},
  {'first_name': 'Alexey',
   'id': 619,
   'last_name': 'Bardash',
   'deactivated': 'banned'}]]
`
Нужно условие для обхода таких строк.

Comment: @spacenew добавьте дополнительную проверку на наличие ключа, добавил в ответ